# How to use domain class methods on Utils or src/groovy?

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am working with grails application. I want to perform methods like `get()`,`save()`,`delete()`,`findBy()` etc and associated with domains of grails application. When I execute `Domain.get()` method inside **Utils** or **src/groovy** package I get following error.

```
Caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [Domain Class] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [Domain Class] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

Any one help me how can I use domain class method inside **Utils** or **src/groovy** classes?

Comment: You need to provide more context to your question. Where are you using your classes within `src/groovy` from? What's calling them, and in turn calling your domain classes? Try providing more detail to your question, with actual examples of what you are doing, and you'll get better answers.

Comment: import com.chatportal.ShiroUser
class ChatUtility {

 static main(args) {
  def chatUtility = new ChatUtility()
  chatUtility?.display(1)
 }
 
 def display(def id){
  println "ChatUtility Chat User:"+ShiroUser.get(id)
 }

}

Comment: Is the error happening in a test or in the running app?

Comment: @Piyush Can you indicate under what circumstances this error is happening?  Is it happening during tests?  If not, is there anything special about the domain lass that the error is being reported against (written in Java?, pulled in from a plugin? mapped in hibernate cfg file?  anything non-standard about it?)

Comment: Without some more context, it isn't really clear what scenario you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by interacting with GORM entities that have not been properly registered with GORM.  The error doesn't have anything to do with where the interaction is initiated from (`src/groovy`, `grails-app/services/`, etc...).

Not always, but most often this error occurs in a testing environment where the entity type has not been registered with GORM.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/illegalaccessgorm.  That project contains the following.

A domain class:

```
// grails-app/domain/demo/Person.groovy
package demo

class Person {
    String name
}
```

A service:

```
// grails-app/services/demo/HelperService.groovy
package demo

class HelperService {

    int getNumberOfPeople() {
        Person.count()
    }
}
```

A utility class:

```
// src/groovy/demo/SomeHelper.groovy
package demo

class SomeHelper {
    int getNumberOfPeople() {
        Person.count()
    }
}
```

A unit test for the service:

```
// test/unit/demo/HelperServiceSpec.grovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(HelperService)
@Mock(Person)
class HelperServiceSpec extends Specification {


    void "test gorm method"() {
        expect:
        service.numberOfPeople == 0
    }
}
```

A unit test for the utility class:

```
// test/unit/demo/SomeHelperSpec.groovy
package demo

import spock.lang.Specification

@Mock(Person)
class SomeHelperSpec extends Specification {

    void "test gorm method"() {
        given:
        def helper = new SomeHelper()

        expect:
        helper.numberOfPeople == 0
    }
}
```

Both of those tests pass.  If you remove the `@Mock(Person)` from either of them, the test will fail with the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [demo.Person] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

If the problem is happening in some context other than a test, knowing more about the context would be helpful.  Other likely suspects are Java entities that are not being initialized properly for some reason and in some cases domain classes brought in from plugins can be problematic.

Also, knowing what version of Grails you are using may be relevant.

I hope that all makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use domain classes inside `src/groovy` or inside `utils`. You should use services for it. Check out [best practises for Grails architecture](http://www.infoq.com/articles/grails-best-practices):

> **Domain**
>
> - Favor placing model domain specific logic in its own domain. Anything that applies to a single domain with few dependencies should go in its domain class. But keep it restricted to the logic specific to that domain only - more complex business logic that deals with a group of domains belongs to a service.
> - To reuse common partial queries or decompose the complex logic, use named queries and chain them together as required, just like one commonly chains jQuery function calls.
> - Don't mix any other common utility classes or value objects in the domain folder, rather they can go in src/groovy. If these classes need to support validation, one can annotate them with @Validateable.

If you still want to do it, check [this FAQ](https://grails.org/wiki/FAQ#Q%3A%20How%20can%20I%20access%20domain%20classes%20from%20sources%20in%20src/groovy?):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
//…
def book = ApplicationHolder.application.getClassForName("library.Book").findByTitle("Groovy in Action")
```

Comment: I have already created domain class inside PROJECT/grails-app/domain/

Comment: @Michal_Szulc "You shouldn't use domain classes inside src/groovy or inside utils." - Referencing domain classes from code that is defined under `src/groovy` is a perfectly reasonable thing to do.

Comment: IMHO it's cleaner to put all domain-driven logic into `domain` and use `services` methods as glue between different `domain` methods and `src/groovy` helpers` methods. `controllers` would be a flow handlers and of course additional help classes leave into `src/groovy`. Why do you want to mix it?

Comment: A service is just 1 type of class in a grails application.  It doesn't make sense to say that a service is the only place you should ever interact with a reference to a domain class.  There are lots of blocks of code that don't need to be in a service, and some of those blocks of code interact with domain instances.

Comment: Even if one does subscribe to the idea that you should only interact with domain instances from a service, that doesn't address the question asked here.  This problem is not caused by interacting with a domain class from outside of a service.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I like criticism but connected with alternative solution. I'd like to know how to do it better so if you know, please provide better solution.

Comment: https://github.com/jeffbrown/domainaccess/blob/master/src/groovy/demo/SomeUtil.groovy works.

Comment: The recommendation to never access a domain class outside of a service is a preference issue, and I think it is a bad idea.  The recommendation to use the `ApplicationHolder` approach and dynamically load the class just isn't necessary, introduces complexity and doesn't buy you anything.  One can invoke domain class methods from `src/groovy/` the same way they can from a Service or anywhere else.

Comment: The FAQ is outdated but even when that was relevant, it was related to dealing with compile time errors.  That would have no affect on the question described here.  The issue here has to do with the domain class not being properly configured in GORM.  The problem will happen if you call the method from a service or from a class under `src/groovy` and dynamically loading the domain class won't change that.

Comment: It works in this simple example but I remember that out team faced similar problem in larger app and that was the reason we started to stick to proposed by me convention. I do not understand why do you call it *a preference issue*. Could you explain?

Comment: I know `ApplicationHolder` is an ugly workaround for this issue, but still - it worked and works.

Comment: "I know ApplicationHolder is an ugly workaround for this issue, but still - it worked and works." - It doesn't relate to this question.  The `ApplicationHolder` thing isn't working around anything here.  You will get the exact same behavior if you don't do that.

Comment: The `ApplicationHolder` thing made sense a way long time ago but wouldn't have had anything to do with the question here.  That was dealing with an issue with the way that we used to compile things.  You seem to be confused about the relationship between that and the question being asked.  The 2 are not related.

Comment: The error in the question has to do with a domain class not being properly configured in GORM, not always but usually this relates to a domain class being referenced in a test that hasn't properly configured GORM.

Comment: If you don't mind I'll wait until @Piyush test it. Moreover are you going to answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129927/how-to-use-domain-classs-methods-on-utils-or-src-groovy/36130336#comment59902562_36130336 ?

Comment: @Piyush We have a Slack channel and a mailing list if you want to discuss that sort of thing.

Comment: "If you don't mind I'll wait until @Piyush test it." - Of course I don't mind.  I am not trying to be rude, but the recommendation you have made is not a good one and represents the reason that a lot of folks don't care for StackOverflow.  This really is not a good recommendation.  It is specifically a bad idea.  You have copied, pasted and recommended a solution that doesn't relate to this context.